# How to keep the parameters of a compound initializer function argument together with clang format

Tags: c, clang-format

Take this snippet of a compound initializer in a function call

```
foo_make_person(ctx, &(foo_person_desc){
       .name = "Bob",
       .age = 50,
});
```

How can I get clang-format to format this code exactly like that?

Everything I tried always looks wrong. Such as

```
foo_make_person(
       ctx,
       &(foo_person_desc){
           .name = "Bob",
           .age = 50,
       });
```

or this

```
foo_make_person(ctx,
           &(foo_person_desc){
               .name = "Bob",
               .age = 50,
           });
```

or this

```
foo_make_person(ctx, &(foo_person_desc){
                       .name = "Bob",
                       .age = 50,
                   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I concluded that clang-format, as of the current version, just cannot do this kind of formatting.